# Find $\frac{dy}{dx} $ if $ y = 2u^2 - 3u $ and $ u = 4x - 1.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, chain-rule

I'm not absolutely sure on how I can deal with this problem:

> Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx} $ if $ y = 2u^2 - 3u $ and $ u = 4x - 1.$

I am trying to use the chain rule on the following:
$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{du} \dfrac{du}{dx}.$

My work so far: $\dfrac{d}{du}(2u^2-3u) \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}(4x-1)= (4u-3)(4)$.

However I am not absolutely sure I am doing it right.. and I don't have the answer in my book.

Comment: Note that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ should be given in terms of $x$ and not in terms of $u$.  If only there was some way of seeing $u$ as a function of $x$......

Answer (score 2):

What you did is correct, so the final step of yours

$$ (4u-3)(4) = 4(4(4x-1)-3)  = 16(4x-1)-12 = 64x-16-12 = 64x-28$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  But, then you should substitute $u=4x-1$ back in at the end to get

$$
4(4x-1)(4).
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also simplify
$$ y = 2u^2 - 3u = 2(4x-1)^2-3(4x-1) = 32x^2-28x+5$$
Then $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 64 x  - 28$$

Comment: Wow.. our teacher didnt taught us this way of doing it.. it's really simple and it works for every similar problems I have so far...

Comment: @Nex it will only work if substitution will leave you with $y = f(x)$ and no $u$'s. Also, your teacher probably wants you to practice the chain rule.

Comment: @Nex: Expansion is only practical if the exponents are relatively small. Imagine trying it for $y=u^{10} +1$.